# Single term for "upload or download"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, technology

I am creating a base interface for both the class `Upload` and `Download` but I can't figure out what to call it. Is there an English word that can mean *upload* and at the same time *download*?

Comment: "transfer" ...?

Comment: I kinda hate upload and download, because I can never figure out which direction they mean.  Just use get and put like FTP does.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would say **data transfer**. This can be either upload or download.

Comment: or, **file transfer**

Comment: or file/data sharing

Comment: +1 Though there's a technical difference between upload-download and data transfer, this still seems to come the closest.

Comment: @Frozen Fyr Sharing is not upload/ download.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend **file transfer** if you are transferring entire files, by analogy to *FTP* (File Transfer Protocol).

You want to distinguish what your interface does from general network communication, so *data transfer* is too generic.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible terms: 1) bidirectional data transfer and 2) full duplex data transfer.  Here's a [good discussion in relation to USB 3.0.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/usb-30-technology-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not "load", with an "up" method and a "down" method?

Answer (score 1):

*Exchange* can mean upload and at the same time download.